# Communication between RFID reader and PHP

Tags: php, wamp, rfid

I have to develop an application for read RFID tag in a PHP Application.

For this, I bought a reader RFID : http://idtronic-rfid.com/industrial-readers/bluebox-uhf-controller/controller-cx-2ch/

This reader connects to my PC with RJ45.

I installed a WAMP Server on my PC for run the website.

Now, since the website, i have to demand to the RFID reader, to read all RFID Tags in his zone, and return the data to the website.

Have you an idea of how I can do this ?

I have read on the net that the read port (com4 for example) is a solution, but i'm not sure that's the good way of proceed.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: COM4 cannot be a net port. You'll have to study the documentation provided with your reader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check the documentation of you external module to understand exactly how you can communicate with it (which port do you have to read, etc.). Then, you should be able to communicate with this module using the [Direct I/O package](https://pecl.php.net/package/dio) (see [the documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/book.dio.php)). It is not included anymore by default in PHP so you'll have to install it manually on your system.

That's said, keep in mind that:

- This kind of solution will probably not be portable accross OS. If you develop under windows and plan to deploy later on a Linux server, you will probably have to rewrite some parts of the code.
- PHP is a web language, probably not the best choice for communication between a software and a hardware peripheral. You should maybe consider C, C++ or even Python as an alternative.